# How to press [Option] Or [Menu] button in visual studio emulator for android

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

Does anyone know is there any way to press **Menu Button** in visual studio emulator for android?

I google it a long time but could not find anything about this.

And i try to press **F1** **F2** **Home** **PageUp** **Pasuse/Break** on the keyboard and it doesn't work.

If you have any idea about it please tell me, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android menu button hasn't been used on Android phones since Honeycomb / Ice Cream Sandwich (APIs 11 - 15). Since the VS Emulator for Android only has profiles that range from Jellybean to Marshmallow (APIs 17 - 23), there's no menu button. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

If you create a sample app and add this to your MainActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    Log.i("MainActivity", "Key Event: " + keyCode);
    return true;
}
```

You'll see in logcat that the emulator is returning the correct key codes for F1, F2, Home, PageUp, and Pause/Break where they're supported: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

Comment: You are right, in the vs emulator i can't input the menu code (**82**).